# Javascript .bind() doesn't work in this example?

Tags: javascript, bind

Here is the code:

```
var num = 0
window.onload = function() {
    var button = document.getElementById('button')
    button.onclick = function() {
        addNum.bind(this)
  }
}
function addNum() {
    num++
    this.textContent = `hit ${num} times`
}
```

`addNum.apply(this)` and `addNum.call(this)` both work.
I am confused. Anyone can help? Thanks a lot!

Comment: it does work. But `bind()` doesn't call a function, it returns a bound function that you don't use.

Comment: Call and apply call the function with the different context where bind returns a function to be called. You can call the function immediately in JavaScript `addNum.bind(this)();`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`bind` creates a *new* function, with a bound `this` value (and possibly arguments). If you want to *execute* the function, call it with `()`:

```
button.onclick = function() {
  addNum.bind(this)();
}
```

But that's pretty silly to do when `.call` accomplishes the same thing, without requiring an extra `()`:

```
button.onclick = function() {
  addNum.call(this);
}
```

Calling `.bind` without executing the created function is similar to:

```
button.onclick = function() {
  const someFn = () => console.log('foo');
}
```

Here, you created a function named `someFn`, but never called it. Unless you *call* the resulting function, it'll go unused.

Answer (score 0):

While you can see the effects of `addNum.call()` and `addNum.apply()` (the `addNum()` function is executed and it changes something on the page), `addNum.bind(this)` does not have any side effect.

[`Function.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) does not call the functions used to invoke it, it creates and returns another function. But your code simply ignores the returned value.

Your code should be along this lines:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var button = document.getElementById('button')
    var boundAddNum = addNum.bind(this);
    button.onclick = function() {
        boundAddNum();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var num = 0;
$(function() {
var button = document.getElementById('button');
button.onclick = function() {
var addNumX  = addNum.bind(this);
addNumX();
}
var addNum = function() {
num++;
alert("OK");
this.textContent = 'hit ${num} times';
}
});
```

Comment: It's better to indent the code well, and add some explanation.